# oracle-sqldeveloper: where does the output of plugins go to in v21?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

A while ago I wrote myself a nice SQL Developer plugin (back then for Oracle SQL Developer v19.x).
I haven't used for a while and meanwhile I migrated to SQL Developer v21.2.1.204.

When I wanted to run my plugin again, there is no output displayed anywhere!? Where does the output generated by a plugin and emitted by `dbms_output.put_line(...)` end up?

In "Messages - Log" which used to be the tab where the output ended up, the execution only emits a final "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." but nothing else.

For my colleagues who still run Oracle SQL Developer v19 it still works - all output goes to "Messages - Log".

I also tried "Dbms Output" (View --> Dmbs Outout) but nothing appears there.

Thus my question: Where does the output of an SQL Developer Plugin go to in OSD v21+? Do I need to enable anything beforehand to capture or redirect its output?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - problem solved:

while experimenting I had commented the script's preamble

```
set serveroutput on;
set wrap off;
set linesize 4000;
...
```

and then - of course - there is no script output returned to SQLDeveloper.
Everything's working now...